# Adding new column to a DataFrame based on values in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Novice programmer here seeking help. I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
       Name  
0  "jackolsen"
1  "IsabelClark"   
2  "JaneDoe"    
3  "JackOlsen"
4  "JACKOLSEN"
5  "MariaSmith"
6  "JohnSmith"
7  "MaryKent"    
8  "MaryKent"
```

And a list of names:

```
l = list("jackolsen", "janedoe", "johnsmith")
```

My desired output is a new column in the DataFrame which tells me if the name is on the list (value = 1) or not (value = 0)regardless if it is uppercase or lowercase. In this example it would be:

```
       Name         List
0  "jackolsen"       1
1  "IsabelClark"     0   
2  "JaneDoe"         1
3  "JackOlsen"       1
4  "JACKOLSEN"       1
5  "MariaSmith"      0
6  "JohnSmith"       1
7  "MaryKent"        0
8  "MaryKent"        0
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Comment: df['name'].str.lower().isin(l).astype(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.lower`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df['List'] = df.Name.str.lower().isin(l).view('i1')
```

---

```
print(df)

       Name      List
0    jackolsen     1
1  IsabelClark     0
2      JaneDoe     1
3    JackOlsen     1
4    JACKOLSEN     1
5   MariaSmith     0
6    JohnSmith     1
7     MaryKent     0
8     MaryKent     0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df["List"] = df["Name"].str.lower().isin(l).astype(int)
```